# Why i am getting this warning 159:35 warning Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function array-callback-return?

Tags: javascript

i have this code, i am using find to verify if a element exist:

firstly i was using for like this

```
for (const file of files) {
if (data.name === proName ) {
        exist = true
      }
}
```

this code now i have to use filter, find, contains, map what is the best to solve this problem?

```js
lists.find(data => {
  if (
    data.name === proName
  ) {
    return data
  }
})
```

but i am getting this warning

> 159:35  warning  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow
> function  array-callback-return

what happend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function doesn't always return. I.e. the else path doesn't have a return in it.

Just do

```
lists.find(data => data.name === proName)
```

and it'll infer the `data.name === proName` as being returned from the lambda, or arrow, function you pass into `find.`

Otherwise you'll want something like

```
lists.find(data => {
  if (data.name === proName) {
    return data
  } else { 
    return null;
});
```

But returning null isn't what `find` expects; it expects a boolean.